# For loop rename files with lines read from txt file

Tags: cmd

Pretty much a CMD noob. I can handle my way around the basics of bash and I can do my desired function on WSL easily. Here's what it looks like in bash if my question doesn't make sense.

`for file in *.mkv; do read line; mv "$file" "$line"; done < files.txt`

I want to loop through all the mkv files in a directory and rename them with the corresponding line in the text file that already exists and holds the proper naming scheme.

From my understanding, I can't do this with bash on WSL1 because I'm trying to work on a rclone mounted network drive on WSL1, which can't see that as a drive option and, AFAIK, I can't mount it through WSL1 (looks like it is possible with WSL2 and I'm excited to upgrade but that will be a few months out).

Honestly, I'm not even sure this is possible in CMD, the way I want to do it, because I can't find a single thread about it. Or maybe my google-fu is just weaker than I thought.

---

In case it's not possible the way I want to do it, here's a backup question:

The files are currently named

```
ep01_title [crc32].mkv
ep02_title [crc32].mkv
ep03_title [crc32].mkv
```

I want them to be renamed like so:

```
ep01_title [res][crc32].mkv
ep02_title [res][crc32].mkv
ep03_title [res][crc32].mkv
```

I know there's a lot of threads on how I can accomplish the above but that's why it's just a backup question. I'd appreciate if you could show me a way to do it how I originally wanted to do it, similar to the bash command I use. This one is a pretty simple rename and I can see how it could be done with string manipulation but I do this a lot and it's not always a simple batch rename that follows a pattern.

---

Edit with more details as requested by @Compo:

I start off with a list of files in a directory. I run a for loop to echo all the filenames into a txt file.

bash: `for file in *.mkv; do echo "$file" >> files.txt; done`

cmd: `for %f in (*.mkv) do echo "%f" >> files.txt`

Don't know if it matters that I didn't use CMD for it but I used `file` on Ubuntu WSL to get encoding type and line ending type

> ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

I then use notepad++ to make changes to the naming patterns on files.txt. So an example would be a directory that started off with

```
1.mkv
2.mkv
3.mkv
...
10.mkv
```

that I then wanted to pad with 0's so all files have 2 digit numbers. So I'd use notepad++ to very quickly change them to

```
01.mkv
02.mkv
03.mkv
...
10.mkv
```

The above is just a simple example. I know the above example can be done easily without the need for a files.txt because I know how to pad with leading zeroes on bash but the renaming isn't always a simple pattern change.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to `for` loop through a directory and for each iteration read the next line from a pre-made `files.txt` that follows the files order in that directory, and rename them one by 1. The order of the for loop and the files.txt list are directly related so it's just a simple renaming with `ren` if I can read the file line by line and store the string in a variable.

Something like how its done in bash. It would be nice if this worked but it doesn't:

`for %f in (*.mkv) do read line & ren "%f" "%line" < files.txt`

Comment: To clarify, you have a directory containing multiple mkv's and a text file containing a single line string. You want to insert that string at a location determined by some pattern, into those mkv filenames. Is that a fair reflection?

Comment: @Compo Yes, directory containing multiple mkv's. Text file has as many lines as there are files in the directory. So if there was files 1.mkv, 2.mkv, and 3.mkv in the directory, there would be three lines 01.mkv, 02.mkv, and 03.mkv in the txt file. I'm sure there's better ways to do it but, as I mentioned, I know just the basics.

Comment: I think you would need to better explain the relationship between the content and the file listing. The format and layout of the filenames and the text data, including its encoding and line ending type, would go a long way to helping clarify that.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for the help! I've updated my original post with more info since it was too long for the comment and not as nicely formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple single command line mechanism I can think of for performing this task directly at the cmd.exe prompt.

From a batch file however, you could do this, on files in the current directory:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
        'Dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv"'
    ) Do (
        Set /P "in="
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%G" "!in!"
        EndLocal
    )
) < "file.txt"

Pause
```

In the example above, I've assumed that the text file content was matched in quantity of lines to number of files to be renamed. *Ideally the text file was created by using the same command `Dir /B /A:-D /O:N 1> "file.txt"`, in this case, *(used ordering by name alphabetically, please see the command help for others)*. I then assumed that you have edited the filenames within, to match your new requirements.

If you wanted to use the same idea directly in cmd.exe, you could probably do it like this, *(which, as I say, is not a simple mechanism)*:

```batch-file
(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv"') Do @(Set /P "in="&For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C "Echo(!in!"') Do @(Ren "%G" "%~H"))) < "file.txt"
```

---

To better explain, the process, you'd create a file named `file.txt` in the chosen source directory, let's call it `C:\Users\StackHawk\Videos\My Show`, containing the names sorted alphabetically of all of the mkv files in that location.

- Open the Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`
- Type `CD /D "C:\Users\StackHawk\Videos\My Show"`
- You should now be at the prompt like this: `C:\Users\StackHawk\Videos\My Show>`
- Type `Dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv" 1> "file.txt"`
- Edit `file.txt` as needed, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe "file.txt"`

At this point you now have a directory containing *n* amount of MKV files and a text file containing the same quantity of files, in the same order but with your required new naming scheme.

- Now run either the batch file, e.g. `C:\Users\StackHawk\Scripts\mybatch.cmd`, or use the command I provided, `(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv"') Do @(Set /P "in="&For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C "Echo(!in!"') Do @(Ren "%G" "%~H"))) < "file.txt"`

Each MKV file should be renamed as per each line of your edited file content.

Comment: Compo, tysm! Works perfectly on a stock cmd.exe. I ran into an issue with the batch script since my registry is modified at "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" with an Autorun string to open a .cmd file containing DOSKEY aliases and clink on open. Here is the alias file: https://pastebin.com/SxaJXJNK. The batch doesn't work when I load my alias file (works fine with just loading clink). It even reads the echo as a file. Output with alias and last line echo on: https://pastebin.com/Bicemh9w. Output with alias and last line echo off: https://pastebin.com/ziS8B01A. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a file with the new filenames (as you already suspected). Just take the number, add 100 and remove the first digit from that:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
  set /a num=100+%%~na
  ECHO ren "%%a" "!num:~1!%%~xa"
)
```

Sample Output:

```
ren "1.mkv" "01.mkv"
ren "10.mkv" "10.mkv"
ren "11.mkv" "11.mkv"
ren "12.mkv" "12.mkv"
ren "2.mkv" "02.mkv"
ren "3.mkv" "03.mkv"
ren "4.mkv" "04.mkv"
ren "5.mkv" "05.mkv"
ren "6.mkv" "06.mkv"
ren "7.mkv" "07.mkv"
ren "8.mkv" "08.mkv"
ren "9.mkv" "09.mkv"
```

It's easily adaptable to three or more digits; just adapt the "addon" (`100` here)

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `ren` command for security reasons. Remove the `ECHO` when you are sure it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you Stephan! My examples were very simple, as mentioned, just to give an understanding of what I was trying to do. Sometimes the naming is completely different and doesn't follow a pattern which is why I wanted to do it through a file.txt. Your answers are still very helpful, though, since I have no clue how to do this outside of bash.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "backup question" (just replace each  `[crc32]` with  `[res][crc32]`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("ep* [crc32].mkv") do (
  set "file=%%a"
  ECHO ren "%%a" "!file: [crc32]= [res][crc32]!"
)
```

Sample output:

```
ren "ep01_title [crc32].mkv" "ep01_title [res][crc32].mkv"
ren "ep02_title [crc32].mkv" "ep02_title [res][crc32].mkv"
ren "ep03_title [crc32].mkv" "ep03_title [res][crc32].mkv"
```

NOTE: I "disarmed" the ren command for security reasons. Remove the ECHO when you are sure it does what you want.